# Merge Multiple Test Runs into one Jacoco.exec file

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

In my project based on environment variable different set of integration tests are run. For e.g.

```
mvn test -Dconfig=a
mvn test -Dconfig=b
```

Running both lines gives full test coverage.

Now the problem is that each run will create a jacoco.exec file in the target folder, but the second run will override the first by deleting the target folder.

I want to use jacoco merge to combine the exec files but I am not sure how to go about it.

I can change the output directory to somewhere else other than target and merge but then how will I maintain version or do I have to add a line to delete the folder after merge is done.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a separate exec as per your run/s. ( eg `a.exec` and `b.exec` )
post that you can use `jacoco:merge` plugin to merge your exec files to get one exec, which will have your complete coverage.

Reference for merging exec files via maven.

> http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/merge-mojo.html

Comment: Can we merge execc files from different version of jacoco from different projects? like 0.8 and 0.7?